# Auto Fill Textboxes from database when choose element in combobox without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I want auto fill textboxes from database when user choose an element in combo box.
with jQuery or java script in php.
$name when choose an element get text of that

```
<select name="Work_Subject" id="id2" onchange="">
             <option value="*" selected>*</option>
             <option value="1">TD</option>
             <option value="2">HW</option>
             <option value="3">Re</option>
             <option value="4">AM</option>
             <option value="5">Other</option>
</select>

  $name=$_POST['work_suubject'];
        $arrResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cr_time name=".$name."",$con);
        if((mysql_num_rows($arrResult))>0){
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($arrResult);}
       <input type="text" name="title_affect" id="title_affect" value="<?php $row['name']?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML FILE

```
<select name="Work_Subject" id="id2">
         <option value="*" selected>*</option>
         <option value="1">TD</option>
         <option value="2">HW</option>
         <option value="3">Re</option>
         <option value="4">AM</option>
         <option value="5">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="result" />
<input type="text" class="result" />
<input type="text" class="result" />
<input type="text" class="result" />
<input type="text" class="result" />
```

JS

```
$("#id2").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: {'value':$(this).val()},
        success: function(msg){$('.result').val(msg)}
    });
});
```

some.php

```
make your code and echo result 

Eg. echo $result; die;
```

Comment: thank you for help but your code is worked for one textbox and i want fill 5 text box when choose an element in combo box.

Comment: then put 5 textbox and change id to class. I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id2").change(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: "element="+$(this).val(),
      success: function(msg){
        alert( "Прибыли данные: " + msg );
      }
    });

  });
});
```

Select the item, then pass a value, then do work on the server and then give the result

Comment: thank you for help but your code is worked for one textbox and i want fill 5 text box when choose an element in combo box.